# What is the "m" in timestamp and how to get timestamp without "m"?

Tags: go, timestamp

In Go , for time.Now() getting timestamp trailing with **m=xx.xxxx...**, what does that **m** means?

How to remove it while printing or Is there any other ways or function to get timestamp without **m**

For Example:- for time.Now() getting output =>  2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC **m=+0.000000001**

But i need output like this => 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: Always consult the package documentation first and read it in full.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> i need output like this => 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC

---

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> import "time"
>
> Monotonic Clocks
>
> Operating systems provide both a “wall clock,” which is subject to
>   changes for clock synchronization, and a “monotonic clock,” which is
>   not. The general rule is that the wall clock is for telling time and
>   the monotonic clock is for measuring time. Rather than split the API,
>   in this package the Time returned by time.Now contains both a wall
>   clock reading and a monotonic clock reading; later time-telling
>   operations use the wall clock reading, but later time-measuring
>   operations, specifically comparisons and subtractions, use the
>   monotonic clock reading.
>
> The canonical way to strip a monotonic clock reading is to use t =
>   t.Round(0).
>
> [func (Time) Round](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Round) 1.1
>
> ```
> func (t Time) Round(d Duration) Time
> ```
>
> Round returns the result of rounding t to the nearest multiple of d
>   (since the zero time). The rounding behavior for halfway values is to
>   round up. If d <= 0, Round returns t stripped of any monotonic clock
>   reading but otherwise unchanged.
>
> [func (Time) String](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) String() string
> ```
>
> String returns the time formatted using the format string
>
> If the time has a monotonic clock reading, the returned string
>   includes a final field "m=±", where value is the monotonic
>   clock reading formatted as a decimal number of seconds.

---

> The canonical way to strip a monotonic clock reading is to use
>   `t = t.Round(0)`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t.Round(0))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/nglDbs9IGdU

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 6):

All you need is:

```
    time.Now().Truncate(0)
```

According to doc on time.String()

> If the time has a monotonic clock reading, the returned string includes a final field "m=±", where value is the monotonic clock reading formatted as a decimal number of seconds.

And time.Truncate() godoc says:

> Truncate returns the result of rounding t down to a multiple of d (since the zero time). If d <= 0, Truncate returns t stripped of any monotonic clock reading but otherwise unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Use time formatting

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"))
```